# Querying a Single Column with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I want to fetch array of values of a single column in a table, for example, I have a table named Customer(ID,Name), and want to fetch ids of all customers. my query in LINQ is:

```
var ids = db.Customers.Select(c=>c.ID).ToList();
```

The answer of this query is correct, but I ran SQL Server Profiler, and saw the query which was like this:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Name] FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t0]
```

I understood that LINQ selects all columns and then creates the integer array of ID fields.

How can I write a LINQ query which generates this query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT [t0].[ID] FROM [dbo].[Customer] AS [t0]
```

Thank you.

UPDATE: i have a function for doing this, and this function causes that result:

```
public static List<TResult> GetSingleColumn<T, TResult>(Func<T, bool> predicate, Func<T, TResult> select) where T : class
{
    using (var db = new DBModelDataContext())
    {
        var q = db.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable();
        if (predicate != null)
            q = q.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
        return q.Select(select).ToList();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
var ids = DBMH.GetSingleColumn<Customer, int>(null, c => c.ID);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static List<TResult> GetSingleColumn<T, TResult>(
   Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
   Expression<Func<T, TResult>> select) where T : class
  {
   using (var db = GetData())
   {
    var q = db.GetTable<T>().AsQueryable();
    if (predicate != null)
     q = q.Where(predicate).AsQueryable();
    var q2 = q.Select(select);
    return q2.ToList();
   }
  }
```

That's the way you should do.

Answer (score 4):

If you only select the fields that you need, it will narrow the scope of the resulting SQL query. Try this:

```
var ids = from customer in db.Customers
          select customer.ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix'd!

```
public static List<TResult> GetSingleColumn<T, TResult>
(
  Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate,
  Expression<Func<T, TResult>> select) where T : class 
{
```

Since you used `Func` instances instead of `Expression` instances, you were using `Enumerable.Where` and `Enumerable.Select` instead of `Queryable.Where` and `Queryable.Select`.  That causes local resolution instead of database-side
resolution.

- [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx)
- [Queryable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534638.aspx)